# geopandas to_postgis: ValueError: geom (geometry(MULTILINESTRING,4326)) not a string

Tags: python, postgis, geopandas, geodataframe, sqlalchemy

I have a [GeoPandas](https://geopandas.org/) [GeoDataFrame](https://geopandas.org/reference/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.html) with a column named `geom` having `MultiLineString` values as such:

`print(gdf.to_markdown()) # using package 'tabulate' to display a markdown table`

```
|    | uid   | key   | install_year | update_date   | geom                                             |
|---:|------:|------:|:-------------|:--------------|:-------------------------------------------------|
|  0 | 57247 |  9247 | 1976-07-29   | 2018-01-21    | MULTILINESTRING (( Human readable coordinates )) |
|  1 | 57248 |  9248 |              | 2018-01-21    | MULTILINESTRING (( Human readable coordinates )) |
|  2 | 57249 |  9249 | 1991-12-24   | 2016-01-31    | MULTILINESTRING (( Human readable coordinates )) |
|  3 | 57250 |  9250 | 1927-02-15   | 2015-01-21    | MULTILINESTRING (( Human readable coordinates )) |
|  4 | 57251 |  9251 | 1991-12-23   | 2015-01-21    | MULTILINESTRING (( Human readable coordinates )) |
|  5 | 57262 |  9262 |              | 2015-01-21    | MULTILINESTRING (( Human readable coordinates )) |
|  6 | 57263 |  9263 |              | 2014-01-21    | MULTILINESTRING (( Human readable coordinates )) |
```

([tabulate](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/) pypi web page)

Now, I'd like to take benefit of the new [`.to_postgis()`](https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_postgis.html) method in order to overwrite an existing [PostGIS](https://postgis.net/) table (using an [SQLAlchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/) [engine](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/engines.html) instance).

But when I do this:

```
import psycopg2
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
connector = psycopg2.connect(**database_parameters_dictionary)
engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://', creator=connector)
with engine.connect() as connection:
    gdf.to_postgis(
        "psql_table_name",
        connection,
        schema="public",
        if_exists="replace",
        index=True,
        dtype={'geom': Geometry(geometry_type='MultiLineString', srid=4326)}
    )
```

I encounter this error:

```
ValueError: geom (geometry(MULTILINESTRING,4326)) not a string
```

What does this mean, I don't get it (heck, geometries should not be geometries but strings?! This sounds strange for a postgis operation...), and how can I fix this error?

I'm on Python 3.6.9 / Ubuntu 18.04 using GeoPandas `0.8.1`, sqlalchemy `1.3.20`, and psycopg2 `2.8.6 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)`

Answer (score 0):

When you pass the connection parameter into .to_postgis it expects a string for the geom column just as if you were doing a SQL query. But if you replace it just with the engine, you won´t have that problem anymore